# Bat script using WMIC causing issues

Tags: command-line, script, batch, batch-file, wmic

I am trying to write a script to install the correct display driver. Long story short on newer systems when you add a dedicated card the onboard is no longer disabled so when I run this command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_videocontroller get pnpdeviceid/value 2^>NUL ^| find /i "pnpdeviceid"') DO set vdcd=%%i
```

my vdcd variable is now set with the pnpdeviceid of the onboard, but when I add the wmic Where verb i get no result using this command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_videocontroller Where DeviceID="VideoController1" get pnpdeviceid /value 2^>NUL ^| find /i "pnpdeviceid"') DO set vdcd=%%i
```

Running just

```
wmic path win32_videocontroller Where DeviceID="VideoController1" get pnpdeviceid
```

does result with the desired primary display adapter. I can make a mess of things and "MAKE" it work but I like to keep my scripts as clean as possible.. Making it work by writing the simple command to a txt file and then running a separate for command to read the txt document.

A user on another site suggested I try this as a workaround

```
@echo off
wmic path win32_videocontroller get deviceid, pnpdeviceid | for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('find /i "videocontroller1"') do set x=%%a
echo %x% 
pause
```

but I get an output of this

```
G:\Drivers\Display>set x=PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_104A&SUBSYS_35451458&REV_A1\4&14466D94
&0&0008

ECHO is off.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

for some reason at the `do set x=%%a` it is instead echoing `set x=%%a` and not setting a value at all... very strange indeed...

Any ideas (other then "use a different language", which was also suggested)?

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help) to see how to set up the formatting properly.

Comment: holy crazy craptastic... lol

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from peculiarities of how CMD (batch) parses your code. The command within the FOR IN() clause gets parsed twice, and the parser ends up converting the `=` into a space unless it is escaped or quoted.

Here is a solution using escape:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_videocontroller Where DeviceID^="VideoController1" get pnpdeviceid /value 2^>NUL ^| find /i "pnpdeviceid"') DO set vdcd=%%i
```

Here is a solution using quotes:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_videocontroller Where "DeviceID='VideoController1'" get pnpdeviceid /value 2^>NUL ^| find /i "pnpdeviceid"') DO set vdcd=%%i
```

It is actually possible to use quotes around the entire command and eliminate all escapes:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('"wmic path win32_videocontroller Where DeviceID='VideoController1' get pnpdeviceid /value 2>NUL | find /i "pnpdeviceid""') DO set vdcd=%%i
```

Quoting and escaping in batch can get confusing very quickly, but trust me, there really are rules and it is totally predictable :-) It just may not seem that way.

Answer (score 0):

The position of your `>nul` is the problem.  `find` isn't going to find anything because you are directing the output of the command to `nul`.  If you just don't want it to display the output, you have to redirect the `find` command to `nul` as it is what is displaying to con

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_videocontroller Where DeviceID="VideoController1" get pnpdeviceid /value 2 ^| find /i "pnpdeviceid"^>NUL') DO set vdcd=%%i
```